# Show the configuration values in the text field of form in prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I am creating a module in prestashop 1.7 to save my settings.

Also I created a form to display my settings. Form sample is shown below:-

```
//display form function

public function renderCustomerForm()
{
    $this->fields_form = array(
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Customer  Settings'),
            'icon' => 'icon-time'
            ),
        'input'=>array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('BusinessCustomerFlag'),
                'name' => 'C_BUSINESS_FLAG',
                'lang' => false,
                'required' => true
                ),      

            ),
        'submit' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),           
            'name' => 'submitCustomer',            
            'icon' => 'process-icon-save'  
            )
        );
```

I am saving this values in configuration table using configuration class functions.

I know how to retrieve it but don't know how to show in the form. Please some one guide on this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to helper on your module (before generateForm):

```
$helper->fields_value = $this->getFormValues();
```

and add function to define values:

```
public function getFormValues()
{
    $fields_value = array();
    $fields_value['C_BUSINESS_FLAG'] = "some data or retrieved data";

    return $fields_value;
}
```